# Insert row Script Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to insert row via script using this code

```
 function insertrow() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var name = Browser.inputBox('Row Will Be Inserted after ID...');
      var offset=9;
      name= name+offset;
      Logger.log(name);
      ws.insertRowAfter(name); 
}
```

But would to insert via INPUT BOX a reference that should be offset.
E.g. I would insert row after position 18 but user should insert 9 and automatically the script has to calculate 9+9. If I try my script does `18+9=189`.

How can face with? And If I want to ask to add multiple rows is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **parseInt()** instead:

```
parseInt(Browser.inputBox('Row Will Be Inserted after ID...'));
```

to convert the input (string) to a number (integer).

Here is the updated code:

```
function insertrow() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var name = parseInt(Browser.inputBox('Row Will Be Inserted after ID...'));
      var offset=9;
      name= name+offset;
      ws.insertRowAfter(name); 
}
```

---

In order to add **multiple rows**, for example 10, you can replace `ws.insertRowAfter(name);` with :

```
n_rows = 10; 
ws.insertRows(name, 10);
```

Thus the resuting code would be:

```
function insertrow() { 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var name = parseInt(Browser.inputBox('Row Will Be Inserted after ID...'));
      var offset=9;
      name= name+offset;
      n_rows = 10; 
      ws.insertRows(name, 10);
}
```

> **References:**

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [insertRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex,-numrows)